# how to use "axis tight" on both y axes for plotyy in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have two sets of y axes for the same x axes, so I know I can use:

```
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(x1, y1, x1, y2);
```

to plot it, and that works.

I can label the axes:

```
set(get(AX(1),'Ylabel'),'String','Torque (Nm)');
set(get(AX(2),'Ylabel'),'String','Angle (deg)');
```

but I don't understand how to use

```
axis tight;
```

on each y axis. Everything I've tried either doesn't work or throws an error.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
axis(AX,'tight')
```

I used the [function syntax](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html) and I passed the array `AX` which contains the handles to both axes.